# python - multiprocessing - static tree traversal - performance gain?

Tags: python, tree, multiprocessing, traversal

I have a node tree where every node has an id (node number), a list over children and a debth indicator. I am then given a list over nodes which i am to find the debth of. To do this i use a recursive function.

This is all fine and dandy but I want to speed the process up. I've been looking into multiprocessing, but every time I try it, the calculation time goes up (the higher process count, the longer runtime) compared to using no other processes at all.

My code looks like junk from trying to understand a lot of different examples, so il post this  psuedocode instead.

```
class Node:
    id = int
    children = int[]
    debth = int

function makeNodeTree() ...

function find(x, node):
    for c in node.children:
        if c.id == x: return c
        else:
            if find(x, c) != None: return result
    return None

function main():
    search = [nodeid, nodeid, nodeid...]

    timerstart
    for x in search: find(x, rootNode)
    timerstop

    timerstart
    <split list over number of processes>
    <do some multiprocess magic>
    <get results>
    timerstop

    compare the two
```

I've tried all kinds off tree sizes to see if there is any gain at all, but i have yet to find such a case, which leads me thinking I'm doing something wrong. I guess what I'm asking for is an example/way of doing this traversal with a performance gain, using multiprocessing.

I know there are plenty ways to organize nodes to make this task easy, but i want to check the possible(?) performance boost, if it is possible at all.

Comment: How much work are you performing per node?

Comment: im checking if the current node is the node i want (comparing id), or else moving on to its children

Comment: This may be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It would be great to have the actual code as well to see how you are using `multprocessing`. It looks like you would be able to divide your work based on when you do a call to `find` in your sub cases as you still continue to look through the rest of the child nodes. There also may be some slow down because you are starting and stopping threads and this takes quite a long time to do.

Comment: @Phenalor: that's simply not enough to warrant the overhead of multiprocessing. If performance is lacking, you might want to look into ways to transform your algorithm into an iterative one (DFS with an explicit stack), because recursion can be expensive in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing has overhead because every time you add a process it takes time to set it up. Also if you are using standard Python threads you are unlikely to get any speedup because all the threads will still run on one processor. So three thoughts (1) are your really so big that you need to speed it up? (2) spawn subprocesses (3) don't  use paralellism at each node, just at the top few levels to minimize overhead.